# Why is the only available AVAssetExportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I've set up an `AVAssetExportSession` with just 2 tracks of audio and no video, which plays just like I want it to in the `AVPlayer` - but as I go to export it, the only available `outputFileType` is `AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie` - Why can't I choose an audio format?

When I `NSLog(@"%@", [session supportedFileTypes]);` i get;

```
[51330:c07] (
    "com.apple.quicktime-movie"
)
```

Here is my code;

```
- (AVMutableComposition *)getComposition {
    AVAsset *backingAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.urlForEightBarAudioFile];
    AVAsset *vocalsAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:self.recorder.url];
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionBackingTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVocalTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack *backingAssetTrack = [backingAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    AVAssetTrack *vocalsAssetTrack = [vocalsAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];

    CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(kCMTimeZero, backingAsset.duration);

    [compositionBackingTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange ofTrack:backingAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    [compositionVocalTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange ofTrack:vocalsAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    return composition;
}


- (IBAction)acceptRecording:(id)sender {
    AVAssetExportSession * session = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:[self getComposition] presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    NSURL *output = [self.urlForPathToEightBarRecordings URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"mix.mov"];
    session.outputURL = output;
    session.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    NSLog(@"%@", [session supportedFileTypes]);
    [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^() {
        switch (session.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                NSLog(@"It's done...hallelujah");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah right so the reason why it was only giving me the option of quicktime movie was because my preset was set to `AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality` which is a video only preset I guess. I set my preset to `AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A` and the output file type to `AVFileTypeAppleM4A` and export was a success!

Comment: Yes i did that. But its taking a small time. Can i use pass through preset to export mp3 file???

Answer (score 0):

You can use these settings for 128kbps

Preset time: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality

OutputfileType AVFileTypeMPEG

format: mp4